# ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to write my first table create script with column definitions.  I have tried several things to get this error to go away, but to no avail.  Please take a look to see if their is anything obvious in my code below:

```
CREATE TABLE CD_TYPE (
CD_TYPE VARCHAR2(4) PRIMARY KEY,
CD_FORMAT VARCHAR2(10) 
);

CREATE TABLE MANUFACTURER (
MANUFACTURER_NUM NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
MANUFACTURER_NAME VARCHAR2(30) 
);

CREATE TABLE CD_TITLE (
CD_NUM    NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY,
TITLE   VARCHAR2(30),
MANUFACTURER_NUM VARCHAR2(30) FOREIGN KEY,
CD_TYPE   VARCHAR2(4) FOREIGN KEY,
ACQUIRED_DATE DATE,
ORIGINAL CHAR(1) 
);

CREATE TABLE CD_SN (
CD_NUM NUMBER(4) PRIMARY KEY FOREIGN KEY,
SERIAL_NUM VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
NUM_LIC_REMAIN NUMBER(2) 
);
```

Comment: Is that how FOREIGN KEYs are declared? Don't you need to say what they reference?

Comment: And your last table cannot have two PRIMARY KEYS. If you want a primary key with two columns, that would be PRIMARY KEY (CD_NUM, SERIAL_NUM).

Comment: As for the ORA-00911. How do you execute that SQL? In many situations (such as through JDBC), you have to run just one command at a time, and it does not like the trailing semicolon.

Comment: Trying these changes.....

Comment: I am just using the SQL Commands tab in Oracle Express

Comment: Thilo.  I made all of the changes and then ran them one at a time and got no errors.  When I ran the script after correcting all of the keys, it also ran just fine.  Thanks for your quick suggestions and help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: If you're using these tables in Apex, I recommend you change the `CHAR(1)` to use `VARCHAR2(1)`. There's a little gotcha with checkboxes and list items if you use them with a CHAR.

Comment: Use documentation, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm. The you can find information about correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the columns reading

```
 MANUFACTURER_NUM VARCHAR2(30) FOREIGN KEY,
```

You forgot to specify what table these columns refer to.

You to that with a `REFERENCES` clause:

```
create table cd_title (
cd_num    number(4) primary key,
title   varchar2(30),
manufacturer_num             REFERENCES MANUFACTURER,
cd_type                      REFERENCES CD_TYPE,
acquired_date date,
original char(1)
);
```

Alternatively, you can specify the name for the foreign key with a `CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (...) REFERENCES ...` clause:

```
create table cd_title (
cd_num    number(4) primary key,
title   varchar2(30),
manufacturer_num,
cd_type,
acquired_date date,
original char(1),
--
CONSTRAINT cd_title_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (manufacturer_num) REFERENCES manufacturer,
CONSTRAINT cd_title_fk2 FOREIGN KEY (cd_type         ) REFERENCES cd_type
)
```